# Php7 construct a 'define' method using a loop; is it possible?

Tags: php, arrays, methods, php-7

In php 7, is it possible to construct a definition, `define`, as an array using a loop?

**Example:** `define( "CUSTOMER", ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]);`

I would like to try something like:

`//FROM EXTERNAL USER CLASS: $user = new $User;`

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table";

 $results = $user->db->query($sql);
 $i = 1;
 while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    define( "CUSTOMER", [
       $i => $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'],
    ]);
 $i++;
 }
```

I have tried to make this work, but cannot seem to get the logic right.
I am only able to get one result from the loop though there are multiple entries in the DB.

var_dump($rows); reveals that the query is fine, however the issue seems to be iteration within the construction of the `define` array.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps someone could explain in more detail why this question would get down voted. I understand that I did not supply a fiddle and that my logic, was at best, novice in terms of my approach within PHP. Ignorance is after all the driving force behind this machine known as 'stackoverflow'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this. Create an `array` which you want to define , after that use it for defining constant. The problem in your code comes, when you got multiple rows.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

$results = $user->db->query($sql);
$constantArray=array();
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
    $constantArray[]=$row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'];
}

define("CUSTOMER", $constantArray);
```